# Help for remembering a fantasy book with water and fire people at war

Tags: story-identification

I recently remembered a book I read end 90 beginning 2000, but was very probably older than that, I thought I could find it quickly, but R.R.Martin is overshadowing all other research...

The book is about two society, one of "fire" people, who lives in a desert and fear water (I don t remeber if they drink very little or if water is just a poison to them, but it s bad for them), and "water" people, who can t live if too far from water. The two society are at war for some reason, and a "fire" boy end up loving a "water" girl.

I also remember that a anime movie was made based on this book, but was more lighthearted and centered around the two lover.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sea_Prince_and_the_Fire_Child - Not a book though...

Comment: @Richard The boy is from the fire people, not the oposite, and the movie's style of drawing was more "Avatar the last airbender" than old school handdrawing, but a good strike thought

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: Cover of "Les Enfants de la Pluie". It shows a boy and a girl standing shoulder to shoulder turned away from each other, but looking at each other from the side. On the right is a boy colored red. He is holding a sword, and in the background behind him is an orange desert. On the left is a girl colored blue. She is crossing her arms, and behind her is a blue waterside town.]

I think the anime movie you're talking about is [The Rain Children](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rain_Children) (in French *Les Enfants de la Pluie*). It's based on a book by Serge Brussolo (a French writer), *A l'image du dragon*. I couldn't find the title in English, though.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rain_Children#Plot):

> Since the Great Sundering, the world has been divided into two parts : the land of fire, a vast desert inhabited by the people of the Pyross, and the land of water, inhabited by the Hydross. The Pyross have red skin, and stocky, muscular features; water burns their flesh and rain is lethal to them. They use sunstones (shining crystals) as both money and energy source. During the rainy season, they stay locked in their city of stone and cannot get out; they protect themselves from the rain and from the wild water dragons who wander into Pyross territory during the rainy season. The Hydross, on the other hand, have curvy features and blue or turquoise skin, and water is vital to them. In summer, the Hydross turn into stone statues and are thus vulnerable, while the Pyross can get out and venture into Hydross territory to destroy as many Hydross statues as they can before the rainy season starts again. The two people know very little about one another, and they cannot even touch one another, as the contact of Hydross skin burns the Pyross, and vice versa.
>
> Peace between Hydross and Pyross seems impossible, but two young people, a Pyross named Skan and a young Hydross, Kallisto, meet one another in improbable circumstances and try desperately to stop the eternal war.